# BufferWriter not converting integers above 383

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to convert numbers to byte array form. There's a simple trick that goes like this:

```
int input = number;    
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(input).array();

for(int i = 0 ; i < bytes.length ; i++)
            System.out.println(bytes[i]);
```

Works like a charm, except when I exceed integer value 383 (Bytes: 0 0 1 127), it automatically results in an array with integer value 319 (Bytes: 0 0 1 63) when writing it to a file:

```
BufferedWriter out;

for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length ; i++)
            out.write(input[i]);
```

Is there a solution to that?

Comment: For 384, I get [0, 0, 1, -128] (which is, I believe, the correct byte pattern: 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x80). What input gives you [0, 0, 1, 63]?

Comment: i dont know how you arrived at that answer. When i tried to execute, am getting **Bytes: (0 0 1 -128) for value 384, Bytes: (0 0 1 -127) for value 385** and so on which is reasonable, as the negative value indicates the 2's compliment being set.

Comment: Anything above 383, including 384 itself. I'm using Java 1.7 64-bit if that might point to anything.

Comment: Same version here as well. But doesn't seem like thats happening.

Comment: @TedHopp, yeah same here as well. And it continues the same reasonable way for bigger numbers also

Comment: Are you inspecting the values in `bytes` in a debugger, or are you printing them? If the latter, please show the code.

Comment: By printing. I'll add the code right away...

Comment: will ``ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(383).getInt(0)`` print 319?

Comment: When I appended a display right after the bytes [], it got the right output: [0, 0, 1, -128]

However, the bytes were written to a file and from reading they get [0, 0, 1, 63].

Comment: Sounds like a problem with either reading or writing negative byte values to the file, not a problem with `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: You can see your code in action (with `System.out.println`, before the recent edit(s)), producing the correct results, at http://ideone.com/ETzHyK

Comment: At first, I was mistakingly displaying the bytes written to a file (Rather than the ones in the program), which did result in misunderstanding where the problem started. I modified the question to be BufferedWriter instead.

Comment: BufferedWriter is for writing text, not binary.  You could use DataOutputStream instead.

Comment: That indeed solved my problem! Reading the bytes is now working properly